# How to show direction of mobile on map like google map?

Tags: android, dictionary, direction

I am using [mapsforge](https://www.google.sk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigjcuSzu3OAhVBQBQKHeAYD_oQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmapsforge%2Fmapsforge&usg=AFQjCNFKMGjhi71WuRA1VDymAmVNv5eyvQ&bvm=bv.131286987,d.d24) and I can show user current location on the map, I want to show user direction as user turn to left or right just like google maps. I dont know how to do that,If anyone has an idea, I will be glad to here that.

Comment: you need to rotate your arrow (bitmap) on base of bearing, then redraw that as a marker on map.

Answer (score 0):

The Android platform provides two sensors that let you determine the position of a device: the geomagnetic field sensor and the accelerometer. The geomagnetic field sensor and the proximity sensor are hardware-based. Most handset and tablet manufacturers include a geomagnetic field sensor. For determining a device's orientation, you can use the readings from the device's accelerometer and the geomagnetic field sensor.

Note: The orientation sensor was deprecated in Android 2.2 (API level 8), and the orientation sensor type was deprecated in Android 4.4W (API level 20).

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html

Answer (score -1):

It will going to be a real time server and client communication, 
you can use NodeJS technology on server side to achieve this.
client side devices will listen to the events that are registered on your NodeJS sockets.